# Asus Zenbook Prime (31A)

Tags: drivers, sleep, zenbook

Just reinstalled Windows 7 on my Zenbook Prime and am working on installing drivers. So far I've got everything working except the screen brightness hotkeys (f5 and f6) and sleep.

I'm not sure what the correct drivers are for these two functions. I'd appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out. Installing the VGA video driver fixed both of those issues...weird.